# Spring xml configuration: No unique bean found: expected 1 but found 0

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:beans.xml");

MyBean myBean=ctx.getBean(MyBean.class)
```

But it returns

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [MyBean] is defined: expected single bean but found 0:
```

But when I do

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
                "C:/pathtofile/beans.xml");
```

then everything runs fine.

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong and how to correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: how did you define at beans.xml?

Comment: in the normal way i guess. because when i retrieve from filesystemxmlapplicationcontext it doesn't throw an error

Comment: Where is your `beans.xml` file located in the project?

Comment: i am using eclipse and it is located in a package in the src folder

Comment: For example, if your `beans.xml` file is located at `src/main/resources` you just have to specify the name of xml file. Like this, `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    "beans.xml");`

Comment: Is Spring allowed to scan that package?

Comment: @vpk:when i do that it complains that it cannot find the file beans.xml. i have a feeling that might be the source of the error. any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @GarryTaylor: You may have a point there. I do not administrative privileges on this computer. could that be the problem? but i guess it should be allowed to scan since it is in my Eclipse workspace

Comment: Can you post the exact location of your file in your project?

Comment: No sorry, I think scan only matters when loading an instance class (i.e. @autowire) and not making a bean from XML. I think your xml file is in the wrong place. Try moving it (for the meantime) to the resources folder (src/main/resources/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/packagewherebeansfileis/beans.xml");
```

Replace all the . in the package name with /

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Saved me today.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch03s10.html